# Exit Meteor Tinytest after after all tests have been completed

Tags: meteor, tinytest

When running `meteor test-packages ./` from automated tests (e.g. grunt files), it would help if meteor exited after the tests were run. Is there a way to do that? The command line help doesn't suggest anything of that sort and [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1307) suggests it's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tinytest is designed to run continuously and reactively test a set of packages.

For continuous integration scenarios, there's a tool called [spacejam](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/spacejam), which calls `meteor-testpackages`, waits for the tests to complete, then sends a SIGTERM signal to meteor.

```
$ npm install -g spacejam
$ spacejam test-packages ./

spacejam: spawning meteor
[[[[[ Tests ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
spacejam: meteor mongodb is ready
I20141129-21:12:34.361(-8)? test-in-console listening
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:4096/
spacejam: meteor is ready
spacejam: spawning phantomjs
phantomjs: Running tests at http://localhost:4096/ using test-in-console
S: tinytest - Moment.is : OK
C: tinytest - Moment.is : OK
passed/expected/failed/total 2 / 0 / 0 / 2
##_meteor_magic##state: done
spacejam: phantomjs exited with code: 0
spacejam: killing meteor
spacejam: meteor killed with signal: SIGTERM
```

Comment: Now if `spacejam` would only [also] [output JUnit XML](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/spacejam/issues/19), it would be even more useful for CI!

Comment: By the way, putting this file in your repo will allow you to integrate with circleci.com, which is free for small needs:

Comment: dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - ~/.meteor
  override:
    - meteor || curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
    - npm install -g spacejam

test:
  override:
    - spacejam test-packages